# Will a MacBook7,1's SuperDrive work in a MacBook2,1?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, optical-drive

A friend of mine has a MacBook2,1 mid 2007 with a dead Combo Drive (long story short, someone at the Apple Store put the wrong drive in), and I have a MacBook7,1 (mid 2010) that I tore down for parts.

Normally I'd just try this myself but the drive is at my parents house an hour away and gas is $3.49 a gallon. Does anyone know if they're interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. The MacBook7,1 has a SATA connection for the optical drive, whereas the MacBook2,1 has an ATA connection for the optical drive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the drive goes, it's a standard ATA DVD drive, however it may have a different case (for the screws/connectors).

Your best bet (unless someone can come up with the exact answer) is to check iFixit and find the tear down of the models and compare the pictures. I'd say they are, but Macbook internals have changed a lot and you might have to disassemble the whole SuperDrive.

For example [here's](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2010-Optical-Drive-Replacement/3074/1) the guide to replace the SuperDrive on the mid-2010 model.

Find the other model and compare. But remember, the drive itself may be faster/better but it's the same drive you'll find in any other PC, no matter how *Super* Apple makes it sound ;)