# Are these two optical drives interchangeable?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, optical-drive

I have two laptops:

- MacBook 2,1
- MacBook Pro 5,3

As the optical drive of the MBP has issues, I would like to use the optical drive from the MB.
The MB optical drive has an ATA interface, while the MBP drive uses SATA. Googling I find that these interfaces [are not interchangeable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9692/24324). 
However, both use the ATAPI protocol, so this made me doubt my earlier conclusion.

This is the information of the MB optical drive:
[image: MacBook optical drive info]

This is the information of the MBP optical drive:
[image: MacBook Pro optical drive info]

Will I be able to swap-out the UJ-868 (MBP) drive with the GSA-S10N (MB) drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**They are not interchangeable.**

ATA is also referred to as [PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) (Parallel ATtachment or IDE). [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Cables.2C_connectors.2C_and_ports) is is Serial ATA or Serial Attachment.  [ATAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Packet_Interface) (ATA Packet Interface) is just the drive communication protocol used to "talk" to the drives.

Using the "larger" drives as a visual reference since the micro connectors' size in a laptop can be deceiving, we can see the huge difference between a PATA connector and the SATA connector.

[image]
[image]

Even though they use the same *[protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol)*, the two are completely different.  A protocol is how devices communicate (what runs over the cable).

Let's use a more common interface, electricity, as an analogy.  Even though the exact same thing (electric current) runs through these devices, they are no way "compatible."  The first picture is a US 220V appliance outlet and the second is a common PC electrical plug.  If you *were* to get one connected to the other, it most definitely wouldn't work (ever again).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably worth a mention that ATAPI is just a protocol, and is supported by a number of different physical bus types, including ATA.

Comment: The PC would likely work fine on a 220V appliance outlet, as PC power supplies tend to be built to work worldwide (usually 110-250V).

Comment: If this were a desktop, you could get an adapter, but there's no way you can fit a PATA-to-SATA adapter into a laptop.